# Calculating a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I've been trying to find the coefficient of $x^{80}$ as you can see below. I'm having trouble following the steps here, specifically the second line. How did it go from the first line to the second line? What happens after that? I'm lost after the first one. Haven't really seen anything like this before.

[image]

Comment: Note that $1-x^8=(1-x^4)(1+x^4)=(1-x)(1+x+\dots + x^7)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1-x^8=(1-x^4)(1+x^4)=(1-x)(1+x+\dots + x^7)$, so we have the second line.

Since it is a generating function, $\frac{1}{(1-x^8)^3} = 1+a_8 x^8 +a_{16}x^16 + a_{24} x^24 +\dots$, or equivalently the $i$-th coefficient of the series is $0$ unless $8$ divides $i$.

So if we want to count the $80$-th coefficient of $(1+\dots +x^8 + \dots x^11)(1+a_8 x^8 +a_{16}x^16 + a_24 x^24 +\dots)$, we only have to pay attention to terms $1$ and $x^8$, since they are the only terms that might give $x^80$ at the end.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. But what happens to 1/1-x? Why does (1-x)(1+x+...+x^7) go on the numerator rather than the denominator?

Comment: @Andrew $\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1+x+\dots x^7}{(1-x)(1+x+\dots x^7)} = \frac{1+x+\dots x^7}{1-x^8}$

Comment: Thanks! One last question, how does 1+...+x^8+...+x^11 get divided up into two functions in line 3 to 4?

Comment: @Andrew You only have to care about terms with $x^{8i}$, since they are the only terms that will give you $x^80$.